# Git Remove Specific commits

Tags: git, revert

Lets say i've commits 1,2,3,4,5. commit 2 and 5 is mine the rest is done by others. becuase of 3,4 commit there is some error! **I've pushed the commits.**
commit 5 is the changes i want to apply on commit 2.

i want to rollback to commit 2 and apply my new changes commmit 5.

How should i remove specific commits 3 and 4 alone?

Answer (score 1):

Do a rebase:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

This will open an editor window; just delete the `pick` lines corresponding to commits 3 and 4. Quit the editor: the rebase will proceed.

Note: dangerous, and source of conflicts; if the rebase fails for some reason, either fix it (by hand; see the `git rebase` manpage) or abort it with `git rebase --abort`)

When the rebase is done, push with the `-f` option. But people working with you on this repo will not thank you!

Comment: i've commited the recent changes!

Comment: Then skip the stash part ;) Editing

Comment: OK, please edit your post with these details, since those are important details...

Comment: recent commit can't be added!

Answer (score -1):

Here's another method just for variety.

What you should ideally do is to create new commits on top of 5 which will revert the code in commits 3 and 4.

If you have not pushed these commits, you can also do a cherry-pick. Say your repo's HEAD points at 5 and it is the branch master.

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4-> 5 (HEAD, master)
```

```
git co -b temp

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 (HEAD, master, temp)
```

```
git co master
git reset --hard HEAD~3

1 -> 2 (HEAD, master)-> 3 -> 4 -> 5 (temp)
```

```
git cherry-pick temp

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 (temp)
     |
     -> 5' (HEAD, master)
```

```
git branch -D temp

1 -> 2 -> 5' (master, HEAD)
```

I think this is what you want. Although you'll do better to create revert commits on top of 5.

Note: The method given by @fge is more succinct and best if you have done an interactive rebase before. If not, this one will give you a fighting chance since you can always just merge master back to temp and get to the point from where you started.