# How to remove an old commit in Git?

Tags: git

If I have submitted several commits like:

> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4

How can I remove commit 3?

Say each commit I just append that order number to same file.

So for

> 1:  the file content is 1.
>
> 2:  the file content is 12.
>
> 3:  the file content is 123.
>
> 4:  the file content is 1234.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Remove Specific commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21899440/git-remove-specific-commits)

Comment: `git revert` will allow you to revert commit 3

Comment: @xbonez Just `git rever 3`? When I do that, I get a conflict error, but I do not know how to resolve that conflict

Comment: @idjaw my case has a conflict error

Comment: I think you need to illustrate your issue in your question a bit better. Based on your explanation, you were simply looking for removal of a specific commit. If there is a certain issue you are facing in doing this, like your mentioning of a conflict, you should be more specific about what is happening with a better [mcve]

Comment: After removing commit 3, what would you expect the file contents to be?

Comment: @1615903 I expect 124, but this is just a simple example, most time, there are a lot of changes which not done by myself, how can I just revert everything affected by that commit?

Answer (score 2):

This all depends on what you mean by "remove a commit".

1. If you want to undo the changes from a previous commit, use `git revert`. This will create a new commit that is the opposite of the given commit.
2. If you want to delete a previous commit from the change history, use `git rebase -i`. This will give you a text file which you can edit to give commands about how to manipulate the given commits. One of these commands will skip a commit.